# Matrices that are both unitary and hermitian are real?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, clifford-algebras

I am following a book on relativistic quantum mechanics and during some proof related to charge conjugation the author assumes that $\gamma_0$ is real (where $\gamma_0$ is one of the four 4x4 matrices that satisfy the Clifford algebra used for the Dirac equation). While it is true that the most used representations of the gamma matrices have $\gamma_0$ real, it isn't obvious to me that this is true from the properties it has by definition, namely $(\gamma_0)^2 = 1$ and $\gamma_0 = (\gamma_0)^\dagger$. Is it maybe just valid for this specific algebra?

If it helps, here are some extra details about the gamma matrices (Clifford algebra $Cl_{1,3}(R)$):
$$\{\gamma_\mu, \gamma_\nu\} = \gamma_\mu \gamma_\nu - \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu = 2 \eta_{\mu \nu}$$
with $\mu,\nu = \overline{0,3}$ and
$$\eta = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: The pauli matrix $\sigma_y=i\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is unitary and Hermitian but not real!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unitary matrix has its spectrum in the unit circle.  A hermitian matrix has its spectrum in the real line.  Therefore, a unitary hermitian matrix has spectrum a subset of $\{-1,1\}$.  If the matrix is not $\pm I$, it is a reflection which means there is a decomposition of the space $\mathbb{C}^n=V\bigoplus V^\perp$ such the matrix is the identity on $V$ and $-1$ on $V^\perp$.  That said however, the matrix components don't have to be real, since $V$ may be any proper subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$, not necessarily of a form $U\bigoplus iU$ where $U$ is a real subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.